# Creating a dynamic array seems to cause program termination

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment about polynomial. One of the task is to compute the sum of two polynomials and return the result in a new polynomial. But when I run the program, the program terminated itself. When I tried to test which part is wrong, it seems that the line of creating dynamic array is wrong. And I don't understand why, please help.

And here is the header file.

```
class polynomial
{
 private:
  double* coefficient;
  int degree;

 public:
 // CONSTRUCTOR member functions
  polynomial(void);
  polynomial(int degree, const double* coeff);
  polynomial(const polynomial& p);

 //DESTRUCTOR member function
  ~polynomial(void);

 //ACCESSOR member functions
  void print(void) const;
  polynomial add(const polynomial& p) const;
  double evaluate(double x) const;

 //MUTATOR member functions
  void scale(int scale);
};
```

Here is the cpp file about constructors.

```
polynomial::polynomial(void)
{
 degree = 0;
 coefficient = new double [degree+1];
 coefficient[0] = 0;
}

polynomial::polynomial(const polynomial& p)
{
 coefficient = new double [p.degree+1];
 for (int i = 0; i < p.degree+1; i++)
 coefficient[i] = p.coefficient[i];
 degree = p.degree;
}

polynomial::polynomial(int degree, const double* coeff)
{
 coefficient = new double [degree+1];
 for (int i = 0; i < degree+1; i++)
     coefficient[i] = coeff[i];
 polynomial::degree = degree;
}
```

Here is the cpp file.The main problem is on add(const polynomial& p) const part. Others are just for better understanding of the program.

```
polynomial polynomial::add(const polynomial& p) const
{
int degree_diff;
if (degree >= p.degree)
{
    int i;
    degree_diff = degree - p.degree;

    polynomial result;      // The program terminates here.
    result.coefficient = new double[degree+1];
    for (i = 0; i < p.degree+1; i++)    
        result.coefficient[i] = coefficient[i] + p.coefficient[i];

    while (degree_diff != 0)    
    {
        result.coefficient[i] = coefficient[i];
        degree_diff--;
        i++;
    }

    result.degree = degree;
    return result;
}
else    // The case when (degree < p.degree)
{
    int j;
    degree_diff = p.degree - degree;
    polynomial result;
    result.coefficient = new double[p.degree+1];
    for (int j = 0; j < degree+1; j++)
        result.coefficient[j] = coefficient[j] + p.coefficient[j];

    while (degree_diff != 0)
    {
        result.coefficient[j] = p.coefficient[j];
        degree_diff--;
        j++;
    }

    result.degree = p.degree;
    return result;
    }
}
```

I can't find out why the program crashed. Please kindly help.
Fyi, E.g., for the polynomial "3*x^5 + 2*x^3 -x^2 + 7", its degree is 5, coefficient array is {7.0, 0.0, -1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0}

Comment: Why not use std::vector?

Comment: You don't show us the implementation of the constructor. Why? It's exactly the point where you have identified the crash. How should we help you if you hide exactly that piece of the program?

Comment: Please show implementation of constructor.

Comment: You violate the rule of three/five/zero: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: OK. Now that the constructor is shown and looks pretty harmless, are you sure that the program really crashes at the line you have indicated? There is a suspicious use of the uninitialiased `j` variable elsewhere, which is a better candidate for a crash.

Comment: Sorry for missing the constructors. I have added it above. Thanks. I didn't use std::vector because I haven't learnt it yet. I am just a beginner of C++.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's about the variable `j`. I mistyped the "int" inside the for loop, and it makes the program crashed. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate.

Comment: @AndrewPang: I'll turn the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is *not* in the line you have indicated.

When you run this code through a compiler with a sufficiently **high warning level**, you will probably be shown a message like:

```
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'j' used
```

It will point to the line below:

```
int j;
degree_diff = p.degree - degree;
polynomial result;
result.coefficient = new double[p.degree+1];
for (int j = 0; j < degree+1; j++)
    result.coefficient[j] = coefficient[j] + p.coefficient[j];

while (degree_diff != 0)
{
    result.coefficient[j] = p.coefficient[j]; // <----- WARNING
    degree_diff--;
    j++;
}
```

The `j` is uninitialised because the `j` from the `for` loop above is an unrelated variable and has nothing to do with the outer `j`. The outer `j` is left uninitialised. This causes **undefined behaviour** when you try to read from the variable using it as an array index. Crashing is just one possible outcome of undefined behaviour; *anything* is allowed to happen.

So you should initialise `j`:

```
int j = 0; // <----- INITIALISED
degree_diff = p.degree - degree;
polynomial result;
result.coefficient = new double[p.degree+1];
for (int j = 0; j < degree+1; j++)
    result.coefficient[j] = coefficient[j] + p.coefficient[j];

while (degree_diff != 0)
{
    result.coefficient[j] = p.coefficient[j];
    degree_diff--;
    j++;
}
```

Or you use the same `j` in both loops:

```
int j = 0; // still a good idea
degree_diff = p.degree - degree;
polynomial result;
result.coefficient = new double[p.degree+1];
for (j = 0; j < degree+1; j++) // <----- same j
    result.coefficient[j] = coefficient[j] + p.coefficient[j];

while (degree_diff != 0)
{
    result.coefficient[j] = p.coefficient[j];
    degree_diff--;
    j++;
}
```

---

Of course, the real big problem of your code is that you do not use `std::vector`.